# Which mode will an enterprise service bus use?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, soa, esb

i cant write english, but it try my best. My Question is: "Does an esb use topic or queue mode? Point-to-Point? Or does an esb use publish and subscribe?

Thanks so far

Comment: You should start reading about general ESB concepts... as always wikipedia is not perfect, but a good starting [point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_service_bus)

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, an ESB provides implementations of the ["Enterprise Integration Patterns"](http://www.eaipatterns.com/); therefore, the answer is "all/any of the above".